# Flask app works fine in Chrome but internet explorer raising an issue

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, internet-explorer, flask

My flask app renders in the forward direction using buttons perfectly in chrome as well as in internet explorer.

But when I am rendering back using back button(the default arrow button to go back) in explorer it is showing the 'Webpage has expired', but it works fine in chrome.

can anyone tell me the changes that I have to make so that my app would be compatible with internet explorer as well?

I am running my app simply using:

`app.run(debug=False)`

I have also tried

`app.run(debug=True)`

in both cases, the problem is the same.

**After selecting some options from the page, the forward button is rendering the string which is an output of the web page. after clicking back button from that output window it is showing that the 'Webpage has expired'.**

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide the html code if you send that back directly via flask. Honestly its worth thinking about just sending back JSON from flask and let a proper frontend framework handle the rendering. Browsers are a hassle and this could be completely unrelated to Flask.

Comment: So u r saying that I should add the **back** button, instead of using the back button of the browser. ryt?

Comment: No, I misunderstood. The problem occurs when you click "back" in your browser and then flask stops responding?
but yes, a single page application would probably handle this much, much better with its own "back" button. Please provide more code and details what you do in Flask. Do you return HTML views?

Comment: There is no problem with flask I think because in the console it is not raising any warning or error. the problem is only with the back button of the explorer it is showing 'Webpage has expired'.

Comment: I am just rendering with HTML pages with the lists or string type elements. nothing else.

Comment: I suggest go to the Internet options-> Advanced tab -> Find the option 'Do not save encrypted pages to disk' under the security category. If it is enabled then disable it and again try to check for the issue.

Comment: Still the same problem, I think, I have to add the button to render the previous page. Is is the ryt approach?

Comment: Try to add these 2 lines to your code and check again. <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">

Comment: Not working for me. Anyway thanks

Comment: Is it possible for you to share any demo of the flask app that can produce this issue? We can try to test it on our side and try to find a possible solution or a workaround for this issue.

Comment: quite hectic to share the demo here. We can discuss over chat

Comment: You do not need to share any confidential information. We do not require any personal data. You can remove it from your sample and just share the steps to produce the issue. It can help us to understand the issue in a better way. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215678/discussion-between-mohd-bilal-and-deepak-msft).

Comment: I am discussing the issue in a chat.